# Прошу не готовое решение, а помощь в решение. Как пошагово решить эту задачу. Буду благодарен за любую помощь)

Tags: java

JAVA/ На вход поступает строка вида число[строка], на выход - строка, содержащая повторяющиеся подстроки. Пример: Вход: 2[xyz]4[xy]z Выход: xyzxyzxyxyxyxyz

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Повторение символов N количество раз (задачка)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1255794/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-n-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b0)

Comment: Что-то за последнее время слишком много вопросов по поводу этой задачи! хмм...

Comment: Эта задача для конкурса. Я изучаю самостоятельно язык Java и не имею опыта программирования, по этому, мне пока трудно понять алгоритм решения данной задачи

Comment: насколько мне известно, очень похожую задачу задают в одной з FAANG компаний на собеседовании.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/*читай "регулярные выражения"
 *там все ответы
 *https://metanit.com/java/tutorial/7.4.php
 * ну и Шилдт конечно
 */
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class счетчик_строк {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a = "2[xyz]4[xy]z";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[\\[ ,.!?\\]]");
        
        String []i = pattern.split(a);
           for(String word:i)
                System.out.println(word);
    }
}     // с массивом i справишься?
```

Comment: это очень общий ответ.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Огромное спасибо